# nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size cannot be greater than Integer max value: 5410783931

Tags: java, spring, download

**It is becoming when I download files ,how to solve it?**

### My code:

```
@RequestMapping("/download")
public ResponseEntity
<byte[]> download(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("filename") String filename, Model model) throws Exception {
String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/avatars/");

filename = new String(filename.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");

File file = new File(path + File.separator + filename);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

String downloadFileName = new String(filename.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");

headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", downloadFileName);

headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

return new ResponseEntity
<byte[]>(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```

### My xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="defaultEncoding">
        <value>UTF-8</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

### Page erro:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report
Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size cannot be greater than Integer max value: 5410783931
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
Exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size cannot be greater than Integer max value: 5410783931
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size cannot be greater than Integer max value: 5410783931
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:467)
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1675)
com.demo.controller.UploadController.download(UploadController.java:86)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
```

Message erro:
Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size cannot be greater than Integer max value: 5410783931

Exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size cannot be greater than Integer max value: 5410783931
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)

Comment: I downloaded the file size over 2G, what can I do to make it download more than 2G files?

Comment: I think that the posted stacktrace is descriptive enough. Think of how could you read bytes from file rather then using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download large file through spring mvc controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985929/download-large-file-through-spring-mvc-controller)

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve the problem

Comment: By the way, all the String "copy" lines look a bit superflouous. `String downloadFileName = new String(filename.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");` looks quite wrong (if filename contains a character which is encoded differently in ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8). Why not just write `downloadFileName = filename`? Strings are immutable in Java, so usually no need to copy them.

Comment: I will try it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you for helping me solve the problem.**

**My correct solution is:**

```
 InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
 return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

**Do not use the byte,just use InputStreamResource can allow me  download more than 2G files.**